# "Value '' could not be converted." error when clearing ComboBox selection

Tags: wpf, combobox, key-value, selectedvalue, non-nullable

I am trying to clear the selection in a `ComboBox` but get an error

> "Value '' could not be converted."

The `ComboBox`'s `ItemSource` is bound to a key-value pair list.  The `SelectedValue` is the Key and the `DisplayMemberPath` is bound to the Value.

If the `ItemSource` is bound to an ordinary datatype, such as a string, and clear the selected value in `ComboBox`, this error doesn't occur. But I needed it as a Key-Value pair since its a lookup.

Suspect that the error could be because the key-value pair has no corresponding null entry or could not take a null value. Could this a bug in the framework.  How to resolve this. Seen the blogs that says use Nullable value and do the conversion, but doesn't appear to be a good way to resolve this since an explicit conversion adapter have to be written. Is there a better way to resolve this.

Tried setting `ItemSource` binding to nullable value. But get a different error

> 'System.Nullable>' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
//XAML

<Combobox 
    Name="CityPostalCodeCombo"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CityList, TargetNullValue=''}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding PostalCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    AllowNull="True"
    MinWidth="150"
    MaxHeight="50">

//Code:  View Model binding
private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cityList = GetCityList(); 

// City and postal code list
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> CityList
{
  get { return cityList; }
  set
  {
    if (value != cityList)
    {
      cityList = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("CityList");
    }
  }
}             

public KeyValuePair<string, string>? PostalCode
{
    get 
    { 
      return CityList.Where(s =>   s.Key.Equals(postalCode.Value)).First(); 
    }      
    set
    {
      if (value.Key != postalCode.Value)
      {
          postalCode.Value = value.Key;
          OnPropertyChanged("PostalCode");
      }
    }
}

// Populate Cities:
private static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>GetCityList()
{   
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cities = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();   
    KeyValuePair<string, string> value = new KeyValuePair("94310", "Palo Alto");    
    cities.Add(value);  

    value = new KeyValuePair("94555", "Fremont");   
    cities.Add(value);  

    value = new KeyValuePair("95110", "San Jose");  
    cities.Add(value);  

    return cities;
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing `TargetNullValue=''` from the `SelectedItem` binding (or changing it to `TargetNullValue={x:Null}`? The error message suggests that `''` cannot be converted into `System.Nullable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. Note that in XAML `''` represents an empty string and not null.

Comment: have you tried setting  AllowNull="True"  to false ?

Comment: @otzap  Following your post, I tried to set **AllowNull="False"**, I wasn't allowed to delete the string in the combobox. Setting it to false, makes it readonly.

Comment: @dkozl Following your post, I changed **TargetNullValue={x:Null}**, that did not help. I still get the same error, "Value '' could not be converted."

Comment: I had to switch from KeyValuePairs to ComboBoxItemValues.